# Перенаправить подключение с одного сервера на другой

Tags: php, c#

Имеется игровой сервер (auth и world), при подключении, игрок передает лог и пасс на auth и если удачно, то входит в игру.

Я работаю над созданием сервера, который будет изначально принимать лог, пасс и + еще какой нибудь параметр, после обработки, он должен перенаправить игрока на auth сервер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеет ли место быть эта идея, или как лучше сделать? Спасибо!

p.s. Это нужно для того, чтобы сервер обработал переменную, и при ее наличии перенаправил игрока на игровой сервер для авторизации, некая защита...

Comment: Не особо понимаю необходимость первого сервиса. Все равно авторизацию будет выполнять второй.

Comment: `над созданием сервера, который будет изначально принимать лог, пасс и + еще какой нибудь параметр, после обработки, он должен перенаправить игрока на auth сервер` то есть по сути, воровать пароли?

Comment: @ГеннадийП нет,третья переменная будет передаваться через лаунчер, для проверки того, что игра запускается именно через него, эти данные попадают на проверку к серверу, а после проверки, он отправляет игрока на сервер авторизации... Я понимаю, что это бред, но, может есть какая нибудь альтернатива?